# `mv somedir/* someotherdir` when somedir is empty

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing an automated bash script that moves some files from one directory to another directory, but the first directory may be empty:

```sh
$ mv somedir/* someotherdir/
mv: cannot stat 'somedir/*': No such file or directory
```

How can I write this command without generating an error if the directory is empty? Should I just use `rm` and `cp` instead? I could write a conditional check to see if the directory is empty first, but that feels overweight.

I'm surprised the command fails if the directory is empty, so I'm trying to find out if I'm missing some simple solution.

Environment:

- bash
- RHEL

Comment: How could it not fail? The shell is responsible for replacing `somedir/*` with something like `somedir/foo.txt` `somedir/bar.txt` _before `mv` is started_. If it can't do that, `mv` is passed the original glob, which is not (when interpreted as a filename) something that exists on disk. What do you _expect_ `mv` to do when it's passed something that isn't a valid filename?

Comment: ...mind, the shell can be configured at runtime to do something different; f/e, with `nullglob` set it'll just delete the argument altogether and run `mv someotherdir/` with `somedir/*` completely removed; but that gives you an even more opaque error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware of the output stream and the error stream? Output stream has number 1, while error stream has number 2. In case you don't want to see a result, you can redirect that result to the garbage bin.

*Excuse me?*

Well, let's have a look at this case: when the directory is empty, an error is generated and that error is shown in the error stream (2). You can redirect this, using `2>/dev/null` (`/dev/null` being the UNIX/Linux garbage bin), so your command becomes:

```
$ mv somedir/* someotherdir/ 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks Dominique, I didn't consider that option, and it seems like a good one. This would hide other errors, right? Permissions, `somedir` does not exist, etc.

Comment: Yes, redirecting the error output to the garbage does not care about the reason of the error.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want full control over the process, it might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- bash, not sh

restore_nullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob)  # store the initial state of the nullglob setting
shopt -s nullglob                      # unconditionally enable nullglob
source_files=( somedir/* )             # store matching files in an array
if (( ${#source_files[@]} )); then     # if that array isn't empty...
  mv -- "${source_files[@]}" someotherdir/   # ...move the files it contains...
else                                         # otherwise...
  echo "No files to move; doing nothing" >&2 # ...write an error message.
fi
eval "$restore_nullglob"               # restore nullglob to its original setting
```

Explaining the moving parts:

- When `nullglob` is set, the shell expands `*.txt` to an empty list if no .txt files exist; otherwise (by default), it expands `*.txt` to the *string* `*.txt` when there are no matching files.
- `source_files` is an *array* above -- bash's native mechanism to store a list. `${#source_files[@]}` expands to the *length* of that array, whereas `${source_files[@]}` on its own expands to its contents.
- `(( ))` creates an *arithmetic context*, in which expressions are treated as math. In such a context, 0 is falsey, and positive numbers are truthy. Thus, `if (( ${#source_files[@]} ))` is true only if there is more than one file listed in the array `source_files`.

BTW, note that saving and restoring `nullglob` isn't really essential in an independent script; the purpose of showing how to do it is so you can safely use this code in larger scripts that might make assumptions about whether or not `nullglob` is set, without disrupting other code.

Comment: Thanks Charles, though this one is a bit over my head.

Comment: @DavidS, ...if there's any specific part I can explain, let me know. The point of this, while a bit drawn out, is to make it clear what all the individual parts the shell is doing under the hood are.

Answer (score 3):

```
find somedir -type f -exec mv -t someotherdir/. '{}' +
```

Saves you the check, may not be what you want, though.

Comment: Thanks tink, that at least helps confirm that I'm not missing some simple flag or something, e.g. `mv --even-if-empty`.

Comment: Rather inefficient, running a separate copy of `mv` per file

Comment: @DavidS, `mv` can't tell the difference between a glob that the shell chose not to expand (possibly because no matches exist, but possibly for other reasons such as globbing being turned off) and a file that never existed at all. In both cases, it's just "a filename that doesn't exist is present on our command line" from `mv`'s perspective.

Comment: ...I'd consider `-exec sh -c 'mv -- "$@" someotherdir/.' _ {} +` to avoid starting more copies of `mv` than necessary -- at least, if there's any chance of it being a large number of files. Or on a GNU system, `-exec mv -t someotherdir/. -- {} +`

Comment: Thanks Charles, you're of course correct.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Dominique, to report all errors except the empty directory one use:

```
mv somedir/* someotherdir 2>&1 | grep -v No.such
```